# Use Linq to get model using a filtered list from another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have some code that I am using Linq to get all the tickets (ticketIds) someone subscribed to from my TicketSubscription Model and then plug all those ids in to my ticket model to get all the information for the tickets. I tried doing this in 3 steps.  First, pull the UserId. Second, pull all the ids that the user is subscribed to and then finally get all the information for the tickets.  The first two parts look correct but the 3 part I cannot seem to get it to a list.  Here is the code I was trying:

```
var userID = db.Users.Where(u => u.NTUserName == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.UserId).Single();
var SubscribedIds = new HashSet<Guid>(db.TicketSubscriptions.Where(u => u.UserId == (userID)).Select(u => u.TicketId));
var SubscibedList = from ticket in db.Tickets
               join TicketId in SubscribedIds on ticket.TicketId equals TicketId
               select *;

return View("SubscribedTickets", SubscibedList.ToPagedList(page, Properties.Settings.Default.PageSize));
```

I tried to modify some different code that I have to accommodate it but I cannot figure out how to merge the two. Here is the code that I tried to merge:

```
return db.Tickets
      .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)

      .Where(t => t.OpenUser.NTUserName == u).Where(t => t.TicketStatusId == ticketStatusId)
      .OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNumber)
      .ToList();
```

I do need to have t.ticketNotes included and filter out ticketStatusId this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished similar queries by doing something like this:

```
db.Tickets.Where(x => SubscriberIds.Contains(x.TicketId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
db.TicketSubscriptions.Where(u => u.UserId == (userID)).Select(u => u.Ticket)
```

This will give you all the tickets that the user has subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally have with bgriffin4750's help.

```
var userID = db.Users.Where(u => u.NTUserName == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.UserId).Single();
var SubscribedIds = new HashSet<Guid>(db.TicketSubscriptions.Where(u => u.UserId == (userID)).Select(u => u.TicketId));
var SubscribedList = db.Tickets
              .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
              .Where(t => SubscribedIds.Contains(t.TicketId))
                            //.Where(t =>  (Properties.Settings.Default.ClosedID)
              .OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNumber)
              .ToList();

return View("SubscribedTickets", SubscribedList.ToPagedList(page, Properties.Settings.Default.PageSize));
```